# How to specify the default directory for an Excel file SaveAs dialog?

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop, excel-interop

I have a button that the user presses and sends a grid to Excel, and it's saving the file in a directory that I don't want the user to have access to. (It's a hidden share) It then opens the file immediately for the user to view.

I'm using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace, so I'm using an Excel Application and Workbook.

I want the application to open the file from the directory, but if the user chooses to save the file using SaveAs (I would prefer that if the user clicked Save, that it treated it as a new file and opened the SaveAs Dialog), I would like the initial directory to be something like C:.

Here is a bit of the relevant code:

```
Public Sub sendToExcel()

        'Code here that exports data to Excel

        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application()
        Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)

        xlApp.Visible = True

End Sub
```

The most obvious thing I've tried is this:

`xlApp.DefaultFilePath = "C:\"`

This seems to only work if the file is new (hasn't been saved).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you forced to use the Excel interop library for this? Why not using a SaveFileDialog and then use the result to save your workbook to the file choosen?

Comment: Maybe? My first thought was to use Process.Start(filePath), but I lose the ability to make any changes to the file so I went with what else I know, which is to use Excel interop. The point of it being sent to Excel is to open the file immediately for viewing so I'm saving the file on a share and then opening it from there. But this gives the user access to that directory.

Comment: I guess it is critical to know that what I'm trying to accomplish is that the user clicks to send the grid to Excel and it opens immediately without asking where to save.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file have to be saved in that hidden share?

If not, you could save it in the user's temporary folder using the `Path.GetTempFileName()` and open it with Excel from there.

That way, when they "Save As", they will only see the local temporary folder as the source.

Of course, this works only if it is a desktop application.

Comment: I was originally going to do this, but I don't want the user's temp folder to get filled up with whatever they send to Excel. I was going to delete the file after they closed it, but this prevented my application from being used while the file was still open. There's always a way around things though, so perhaps I need to look at this more.

Comment: You could clean it up on the Closing event of your main form

Comment: I thought about doing that too, but it's definitely a preference for the user to be able to close the program without closing the files they have open.